# Disproportionate classification accurary between testset and entire dataset (Random Forest)

Tags: classification, random-forest, accuracy

So I have a multiclass problem (16 classes, 58k samples), for which I decided to use the RandomForestClassifier. 
After some feature engineering and cross-validation I got a test set (13k samples) accuracy of ~33%, and an F1 score of 30%. Given a baseline of 6.25% (1/16), I am content with the results. While my model seems to be overfitting (91% accuaracy on the training set), I can't get the score any higher as I've done copious amounts of cross-validation already.

However, I wanted to see how well the model works on the entire dataset, and I got 79% accuracy and an f1 score of 79%!

This is what got me my initial scores:

```
accuracy = forest.score(X_test, y_test)
f1score = metrics.f1_score(y_test, forest.predict(X_test), pos_label=list(set(y_test)), average="micro")
```

And this is what got me my surprising ones:

```
accuracy = forest.score(dataset, labels)
f1score = metrics.f1_score(labels, forest.predict(dataset), pos_label=list(set(y_test)), average="micro")
```

Now, surely I must have done something wrong, but what?

Comment: I assume you did not compute the OOB for your training data, then your outcome is logical. You trained your model on 75% of the data and you now again use this 75% to attain your performance measures. This results in a huge overfit of course. And this is why your performance is between the performance of the test test and the training set, but closer to the training set as its proportion is higher (75%).

Comment: Sorry, I read what the OOB score does, but could you elaborate on what you're saying in regards to it? If I'm getting you right, having a high score on your entire dataset, as I did, is basically meaningless, corregt?

Comment: The OOB gives you a better estimate of the 'true performance' for your training data. You will see that the OOB Error is much closer to the error you calculated for you test set. And yes, your high score on the entire dataset is pretty meaningless. You always have to think if the data you predict was used in training the model. If this is the case (like in your case) you overfit heavily and your error estimate is quite meaningless.

Comment: I see, thank you. I'm still confused as to why my model is so heavily overfitting on the training data. Seems rather extreme (91% vs 33%), doesn't it? Especially as I couldn't close the gap in any way at all

Comment: It depends on how deep your single trees are (I assume that you did not prune them at all, which is common in RF). Imagine you fully grow a single tree, then this tree will have 100% accuracy on the training data. As you normally use bootsrapped samples to grow your trees in random forest, you will likely achieve something slightly lower than 100%, so like what you got. So no, its not extreme.